# How to use fsockopen to load a url from an xml sitemap

Tags: php, fsockopen

I am attempting to load each url in a sitemap.xml file in an effort to pre-cache them and speed up the users experience.

I have the following code which grabs the urls from the sitemap

```
$ch = curl_init();
/**
* Set the URL of the page or file to download.
*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://onlineservices.letterpart.com/sitemap.xml;jsessionid=1j1agloz5ke7l?id=1j1agloz5ke7l');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
foreach ($xml->url as $url_list) {
    $url = $url_list->loc;
    echo $url ."<br>";    
}
```

and I am now trying to use fsockopen to load each url in turn.

where $url is in this format: http://onlineservices.letterpart.com:80/content/en/FAMILY-201103311115/Family_FLJONLINE_FLJ_2009_07_4

```
foreach ($xml->url as $url_list) {
        $url = $url_list->loc;
$fp = fsockopen ($url,80);
  if ($fp) {
 fwrite($fp, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: $url\r\n\r\n");

        while (!feof($fp)) {
            print fread($fp,256);
        }

        fclose ($fp);
    } else {
        print "Fatal error\n";
    }
}
```

But this is giving me this error for each url:

[12-May-2011 13:34:09] PHP Warning:  fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to http://onlineservices.letterpart.com:80/content/en/FAMILY-201103311115/Family_FLJONLINE_FLJ_2009_07_4:-1 (Unable to find the socket transport "http" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?) in /home/digital1/public_html/dev/sitemap.php on line 32

I have read that I need to: *"just the hostname, not the URL in the fsockopen call. You'll need to provide the uri, minus the host/port in the actual HTTP headers"*

so I tried this:

```
 $fp = fsockopen ("http://onlineservices.letterpart.com",80);
  if ($fp) {
 fwrite($fp, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: content/en/FAMILY-201103311115/Family_FLJONLINE_FLJ_2009_07_4\r\n\r\n");

        while (!feof($fp)) {
            print fread($fp,256);
        }

        fclose ($fp);
    } else {
        print "Fatal error\n";
    }
```

But I still get the same error.

EDIT:

If I change the fsockopen call to:

```
$fp = fsockopen ("onlineservices.letterpart.com",80);
```

then I get a slightly different and better but still wrong response. it seems to be ignoring the onlineservices.letterpart.com section and trying http:///content/ BUT... it has appended: /web/ui.xql?action=html&resource=login.html  tot he end of the url which is our login page so it must be seeing our server...

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily Date: Thu, 12 May 2011 14:40:02 GMT Server: Jetty/5.1.12 (Windows 2003/5.2 x86 java/1.6.0_07 Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=nh62zih3q8mf;Path=/ Location: http:///content/en/FAMILY-201103311115/Family_FLJONLINE_FLJ_2009_07_4/web/ui.xql?action=html&resource=login.html Content-Length: 0

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use curl to get these url ?... And be aware that fetching these urls on server side will not speed up "user experience" since it won't affect browser's cache

Comment: Hi, it isn't the browser cache we are trying to create. The application, which creates DITA XML on the fly caches pages as they are viewed. it is this we are trying to prepopulate.

Comment: Woudl you mind giving me more info on the Curl method for this?

Comment: You already use curl to get sitemap, you just have to adapt this code to get urls you want. For more information : http://php.net/manual/fr/book.curl.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fsockopen is not attented to be used for HTTP request,
Curl is a better choice (and much more powerful).

There is also file_get_contents which can make it quick:

```
foreach ($xml->url as $url_list) {
    $url = $url_list->loc;
    file_get_contents($url);
}
```

Usefull for application cache warmup!